# Import WSDL and create mock

Tags: proxy, wsdl, wso2

I have a system in .net that exposes webservices in SOAP.
I have to remove this system and replace it with another one, but I already have clients using the webservices using the wsdl.
I want to know if it's possible to import the wsdl to be sure to keep the "contract" identical for my clients. And then implement the new system behind the proxy ?
I tried to use WSDL based Proxy, but without success, I probably did something wrong but before investigating any further I want to make sure that it's the right thing to do.
Thanks

Comment: OK I figured out that I had to actually create a Axis2 project.
Now my issue is that the tutorial I follow tells me that I need to create a Carbon Application Project, but I can't find it in the dev studio.

Comment: I used a composite application project.